# How to make Apache Solr disregard the position of text when calculating the relevancy score

Tags: solr

Is the ability to force Solr to disregard the position of text when calculating the relevancy score a feature that's already built into Solr, or otherwise, is it simple to do so?

Comment: can you explain more with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can see [all the options you can define for a field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields) in the Solr Reference Guide. Your specific question is not super clear, but it sounds similar to what **omitTermFreqAndPositions** option does.

Comment: how does omitTermFreqAndPositions work for multivalued fields, or even across fields? will a particular document be scored higher if it's got a query term in multiple values in a multiValued field? also,  how can i prevent a document that has a query term in multiple fields from being scored higher than a document that has the same term in just one field?

Comment: There are too many questions here. You have to set it up and play and see how your particular requirements are reflected with different flags. Have a look at something like http://splainer.io/ to help you in that.